# Debian (Lenny) X2Go Client with 50% CPU

Tags: linux, debian, remote-desktop, cpu-usage

My x2Go Client uses too much cpu power, more than 50% all the time, even when I don't have an open remote session. Does anybody know how to check where the error (?) is located? Thanks

Comment: this also happens with windows x2go client. i think they send jpeg frames endlessly and decompress them each time, so this means its just underoptimised software...

Answer (score 0):

You can use strace to get an idea of what it's doing. strace -p pid